# Javascript Pass LocalStorage Data

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

#### a.html

```
<form>
  <input type='button' id='a' onclick='locstor()' value='Hello' />
</form>
<script>
  function locstor() {
    var x = document.getElementById('a').value;
    localStorage.setItem('x', $('#name').val());
  }
</script>
```

#### b.html

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = $("#name").val(localStorage.getItem('x'));
</script>
<form>
  <p>Welcome to the site <b id='result'>dude</b> 
  </p>
</form>
```

I'm trying to pass a data from *A.html* to *B.html* page using javascript and local storage. However, I was not able to display any changes made to the `result`.

Can anyone tell me why and how?

Comment: why are you combining jQuery selectors and native Javascript selectors?

Comment: Wrap your code in `$(document).ready()` or move your script after `body`. You are trying to set value before DOM is rendered.

Comment: @callback beat me to it.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: You are trying to set value to an element before it is rendered. So when JS tries to get element, it comes blank and so no value is set.